# Static CD/DVD ROM Drive Location

Tags: mount, wine, dvd, fstab

I have read several questions relating to getting WINE to recognise the CD-ROM drive with no success. I have installed a Windows game and when I go to play it, I get a "Please insert disk into CD-ROM drive" message.

I have tried telling WINE to designate the CD-ROM drive D:, tried editing FSTAB to mount the drive on startup, and attempted to find the UUID to see if that makes things easier but cannot find it.

Is there a way to assign a static mount point for the CD/DVD-ROM drive so WINE can address it instead of the random (`/media/"disk name"`)

Comment: I believe you need to give wine the block device ( /dev/cdrom ), not the mounted filesystem.

Comment: @psusi - Played with the settings and put `/dev/cdrom` as D: but still will not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make it static, but on the first time after reboot, you can just start

```
winecfg
```

And use the auto-detect feature for assigning a windows drive letter to the mounted dvd/cdrom drive.

After that, autodetect would only re-map to the (first) mounting - no idea why. For the non-first mountings use *winecfg* as well and re-assign the drive-letter manually *after* the drive has been mounted.